# Maven build infinite repeat

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, build

[image]

When I build maven project with command

```
mvn clean install
```

build repeats infinitely. How can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through shell script its possible.  here N can be a large number.

```
for i in {1..N}
do
   mvn clean install
done
```

Using Windows batch file, below can be used

```
:loop

mvn clean install

goto loop
```

I doubt maven has any plugin to build infinitely. Whats the purpose anyways